# replace() is not working for escape characters

Tags: c#, json, string-formatting

I need to format this json string

```
"\"{\\r\\n  \"result\": null,\\r\\n  \"errorcode\": \"101\",\\r\\n  \"errormessage\": \"OLD VERSION !!! \",\\r\\n  \"failed\": \"Y\"\\r\\n}\""
```

to this format

```
"{  "result": null,  "errorcode": "101",  "errormessage": "OLD VERSION !!!  ",  "failed": "Y"}"
```

> But what i got is

```
"\"{  \"result\": null,  \"errorcode\": \"101\",  \"errormessage\": \"OLD VERSION !!! \",  \"failed\": \"Y\"}\""
```

My function to format the Json string is

```
public string FormatJson(string oObject)
{
    string js = JValue.Parse(oObject).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    string x = js.Replace("\r\n", "");
    string y = x.Replace(@"\", "");

    return y;
}
```

I have called above function as

```
 ErrorResponse errres = new ErrorResponse()
            {
                errormessage = statusR_msg,
                errorcode = statusR,
                resend = "Y"
            };
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errres);
json = func.FormatJson(json);
```

> I have class called ErrorResponse.cs with these properties

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string  result { get; set; }
    public string errorcode { get; set; }
    public string errormessage { get; set; }
    public string failed{ get; set; }
}
```

I have tried 
`string y = x.Replace("\\", "");` too but did not worked. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show how you are getting the string? The replace won't work because it isn't a `\` it is `\"` - an escape character for `"`. If you check the value of `oObject` with the TextVisualizer you wont see the `\"` but just `"`

Comment: did you try to use js directly? You need the escapes to have the quotaion marks, which you still want to have in your second string.

Comment: If i replace " character then i got result as below @Gilad Green its exactly what you have mentioned earlier, so where do i miss ? "{  result: null,  errorcode: 101,  errormessage: OLD VERSION !!!,  failed: Y}"

Comment: Thank you guys for you beautiful comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a viewing bug. The fact that you have quotes at the beginning and end of the string and the `\n` are being displayed as `\\n` suggest that what you have is not the *actual* value of the string but the value of the string as it is escaped to work in code.

I suspect that you are getting that value from the watch window - here it will display it as an escaped string, not the raw value. So make sure that when you are viewing the string you are actually viewing the string (eg via clicking on the Text Visualiser/magnifying glass icon). Obviously if the `\` are not in the actual string then your replace won't get rid of them.

Comment: Exactly in my text visualizer i cannot see any extra unwanted character. Thank you for your comment @Chris